# TabBarController is showing grey colour behind tab bar image

Tags: swift, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I am using an image to set in tab bar controller. some part of the image is transparent and should show view's content behind it. But it is not going clear and always show grey colour.

[image]

Here is the code i am using:

```html
            let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .clear
            tabBar.isTranslucent = false
            appearance.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "homeTabBG")
            tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            tabBar.barTintColor = .clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change

```
tabBar.isTranslucent = true
```

may be it seems to be work because I think for a transparent effect it should set to be as true.

Comment: it does not work.

Comment: is this code is placed after the tabBar initialization ?@AKumar